# Admin-listener disabled in Glassfish 3.1.2

Tags: jsf-2, ejb, glassfish-3, netbeans-7.3, java-ee-7

I am currently working on a project with EJB, JSF and Glassfish. I use NetBeans 7.3 for development.

I am experimenting a very strange issue, I have been looking around (not sure if enough), but have not found any solutions to this.

Every time I stop the server after the project is deployed, I have to go to the domain.xml and in this line:`<network-listener port="8080" protocol="http-listener-1" transport="tcp" name="http-listener-1" thread-pool="http-thread-pool" />` I have to add everytime I want to run the project again the attribute: `enabled="true"`

How can I configure the Glassfish server or NetBeans to resolve this situation?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, anyone, I'm in a hurry, I have not solved this issue yet and I need a solution.

Comment: The `enabled` property is true by default. In addition, you are enabling the "http-listener-1" listener, check the "admin-listener" instead.

Comment: It's the same, the enabled property dissapears from "admin-listener" and "http-listener-1". The problem seems to be other, because in the office computer it works fine, but in my laptop this continue to happen.